# DRF: Create instances of ManyToMany Relations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_items = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through='OrderItem')


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', null=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', null=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

The corresponding serializers:

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ('id', 'product', 'order', )


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = OrderItemSerializer(source='orderitem_set', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'order_items')
```

When I perform a GET-request I get the following result. Every order contains an array `order_items` which has a relation to a product and an order which is fine.

```
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "order_items": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "product_variation": 1,
                    "order": 1
                }
            ],
        },
    ]
```

However, I have problems creating a new order. I tried to overwrite the create method from my `OrderSerializer` but `order_items` is not in the validated data. What would be a good and appropriate way to solve this / what am I doing wrong?

Comment: could it be because you have set the order_items serializer as read only?

Comment: omg... stupid... sometimes you don't see the obvious. Thank you very much for pointing this out